# Subclass that adds

Tags: python, inheritance

First, I have a class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2

class AnotherClass:
    # what goes here ???
```

What I'd like to do is make `AnotherClass` take two inputs,

1. an instance (call it `a`) of `MyClass`
2. another argument, `arg2`,

so that `arg2` can be used to make additional attributes for `AnotherClass`, and every attribute of `MyClass` is also an attribute of the `AnotherClass`, which is not found anew or copied into the `AnotherClass` instance, but found by looking at `a`. (Assume that `MyClass` has lots of attributes, unlike the example shown.) For example, I'd like to be able to do

```
>>> a = MyClass(1, 2)
>>> b = AnotherClass(a, 3)
>>> b.attr1 # found via a.attr1
1
>>> b.attr2 # found via a.attr1
2
>>> b.attr3
3
>>> c = AnotherClass(a, 4)
>>> c.attr1 # found via a.attr1
1
>>> c.attr2 # found via a.attr1
2
>>> c.attr3
4
```

What code should be found in `AnotherClass`?

Comment: this is not the way how inheritance works.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I want with inheritance, or some other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do what you want to do, the constructor you want is:

```
def __init__(self, a, arg1):
    self.__dict__ = dict(a.__dict__)
    self.attr3 = arg1
```

The second line effectively takes every attribute currently assigned to a, and then assigns copies of them to self (__dict__ being the dictionary in which python stores an objects attributes).

Comment: This essentially makes a copy of `a` in the new object, though

Comment: That is why we say `dict(a.__dict__)` and not `a.__dict__`. `dict(myDictionary)` is a idiom for making a copy of a dictionary, meaning that `self.__dict__` and `a.__dict__` still point to two separate dictionary objects.

Comment: Oh, okay, I misunderstood. In that case replace `dict(a.__dict__)` with `a.__dict__`, and then `a` and the new object will always have the exact same set of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The code you want is:

```
def __init__(self, a : Class, arg2):
    super().__init__(a.attr1,a.attr2)
    self.attr3 = arg2
```

However, unless your code specifically wants instances of SubClasses to initialize as pseudo-clones of pre-existing instance of Class, you may find this code more useful:

```
def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, arg2):
    super().__init__(attr1,attr2)
    self.attr3 = arg2
```

Comment: I should have said that I'd like to do this without writing down all of the attributes of `a` in a `super().__init__` call

Comment: You can replace that line with the lines `self.attr1 = a.attr1` and `self.attr2 = a.attr2` and achieve the exact same thing, but I don't think that's what you want either.